# In a photo there are three families (six Greens, four Browns, and seven Grays) arranged in a row. The Browns have had an argument so no Brown will…

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In a photo there are three families (six Greens, four Browns, and seven Grays) arranged in a row. The Browns have had an argument so no Brown will stand next to another Brown. How many different permutations are permitted?

The correct answer is $150\cdot 10^{14}$.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to forget your method, and solve as under.

Permute the 13 "non-Browns" in 13! ways.

There will be 14 spaces in between (including ends), so place the Browns in these in $^{14}P_4$ ways

Multiplying I get ans = $\approx  1.5\times {10}^{14}$

I think there is a typo in the book answer !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a summary of my approach:

The Browns can be together in three different ways:

- All four next to each other ($14$)
- Three together and one somewhere else ($182$)
- Split in pairs ($182$)

*() indicates the number of ways these sets can be positioned in the line of $17$

Using this information, the expression I was left with was the following:

$$17! - \left[(4! \times 13! \times 14) + \left(\binom{4}{3}\times 3! \times 14! \times 182\right) + \left(\binom{3}{2} \times 2! \times2! \times 13! \times 182\right)\right]$$

And I get - $5.44 \times 10^{13}$, which is not correct. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: You have to write, your own, way of solving problem in the questionself

Comment: There's another way Browns can be together: two together, two elsewhere not together.